# Reload DOM element without reloading entire page (modified source html)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, webgl

Let's say I have a `WebGL` application, and the shaders inlined in the HTML document, what I want is to change the HTML document and reload the shaders ***without reloading the entire site***, I got to a fix using an iframe but this is the worst solution possible because the `WebGL` application (with all his callbacks) is running twice, is there a better solution to this problem?

```js
let frame = document.getElementById("iframe");

// Reload the shaders when R is pressed
window.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
  if (e.code === "KeyR") {
    // Reload the html document of the iframe
    frame.contentDocument.location.reload(true);

    // Get the sources from the iframe and reload the shaders
    reloadShaders();
  }
});
```

I don't want the whole page to be reloaded to not lose the state of the thing I'm doing, just live change the shader, I'd prefer also not to use a server dedicated to this task, thanks in advance.

***Example of inlined shader***

```html
<script type="glsl" id="basic.vs">#version 300 es
void main() {
  gl_Position = vec4(
    2 * (gl_VertexID / 2) - 1,
    2 * (gl_VertexID % 2) - 1,
    0.0, 1.0
  );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just update the webgl shader object

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that the shader source is embeded in the html source, because of that I need to reload the dom

Comment: Can you have multiple <script> tags with multiple shaders at page load or do you need to load the new shader code over the network?

Comment: @teddybeard I need to reload the shaders but no the page, for example, lets say im doing a game and I'm testing level 4 and I see something weird, i have a key to stop it everything, edit the shaders(inlined in html) and see the changes at the moment, but currently I do this with an iframe so the game is being executed twice, I'm looking for a better way

Comment: The game will likely completely reload anyways. You're going to need to recreate EVERY program connected to the shader you update. Are you sure you want to do that? Restarting the game seems like a faster option. Maybe you could create a setting where you can quickly fast-forward to the level you need? Maybe just go into the console every time and set `level = 4` or something? Or create a bot that automatically completes the level as fast possible (don't try to make an AI, just simulate click/keypress event with functions)? This would be much easier than recreating each program/shader.